# Finding differentially expressed genes between two samples

Tags: seurat, single-cell

[image]

Hi, I was wondering whether we can find the differentially expressed genes between the `Double-KO` and the `Shox2-KO`. For the `FindMarker()` function, only see the differential expressed gene between different identities. I don't know whether we can find the differential expressed gene between only these two samples.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply use `SetIdent()` to change the "default identity" to your samples and then use `FindMarker()` with the `ident.1 = "Double-KO"` and `ident.2 = "Shox2-KO"`.

Alternatively, you can "collapse" or "summarize" your single cell data into a pseudo-bulk and then use one of the bulk RNA-seq packages.

Comment: Hi haci, that is a good idea. But I have tried to look the script of SetIdent(), find some difficulties to do it. Can you please give me more detail?

Comment: You can set the `ident.use` parameter of `SetIdent()` function to one of the columns in your `meta.data` slot of your `Seurat` object.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right.  SetIdent is used to assign new ident information; you give it a vector of cells to tag.  All you want to do is change the active ident that FindMarkers will use, and you do that with Ident().